# Converting XML into a c# object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

It is complicating me convert an XML to an object in C#.

I want to convert an XML consisting of a list of objects 'Regla' with a series of fields (idRegla, DateFrom, DateTo, and a list of exceptions that may not appear).

I'm going crazy, I do not think it's that hard ...

Here is the XML:

```
<ListaReglas>
  <REGLA>
    <idRegla>2</idRegla>
    <DateFrom>2013-12-01T00:00:00</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2015-07-25T00:00:00</DateTo>
    <Excepciones>
      <FECHA>2013-12-25T00:00:00</FECHA>
    </Excepciones>
  </REGLA>
  <REGLA>
    <idRegla>4</idRegla>
    <DateFrom>2013-12-01T00:00:00</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2015-07-25T00:00:00</DateTo>
    <Excepciones>
      <FECHA>2013-12-25T00:00:00</FECHA>
    </Excepciones>
  </REGLA>
  <REGLA>
    <idRegla>5</idRegla>
    <DateFrom>2013-12-01T00:00:00</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2015-07-25T00:00:00</DateTo>
    <Excepciones>
      <FECHA>2013-12-25T00:00:00</FECHA>
    </Excepciones>
  </REGLA>
  <REGLA>
    <idRegla>7</idRegla>
    <DateFrom>2013-11-19T00:00:00</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2015-12-19T00:00:00</DateTo>
  </REGLA>
</ListaReglas>
```

Here is my class:

```
        [Serializable]
        [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
        public class ReglaRangoResult
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "idRegla", IsNullable = false)]
            public int idRegla { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateFrom", IsNullable = false)]
            public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DateTo", IsNullable = false)]
            public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Excepciones", IsNullable = true)]
            public List<DateTime> Excepciones { get; set; }

            [XmlIgnore]
            public int Peso { get; set; }
        }
```

And this is my code:

```
       [...]
       List<ReglaRangoResult> listaReglas = new List<ReglaRangoResult>();
       XmlDoc xmlDoc = new XmlDoc(rdr.GetString(0));

       foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ListaReglas/REGLA"))
       {
            listaReglas.Add(XmlToObject<ReglaRangoResult>(xmlNode.OuterXml));
       }
       [...]


        public static T XmlToObject<T>(string xml)
        {
            using (var xmlStream = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(xmlStream));
            }
        }
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is the ReglaRangoResult misconfigured class? What is missing? What is left?

EXCEPTION RETURNED:

> 'Error reflecting type 'dllReglasNegocioMP.ReglaRangoResult'

Comment: Try the opposite way and examine the produced XML and compare it to your source XML. I do it this way very often to find the cause.
Providing some exceptions in your question would also help others to understand the situation

Comment: What is going wrong? Any exceptions?

Comment: This is the exception returned: Error reflecting type 'dllReglasNegocioMP.ReglaRangoResult'. As you will see is not very specific

Comment: Any inner exception(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 you can take the XML and select "Edit / Paste special / Paste XML as Classes". When you have done that you can use use XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize in an easy way.

```
 var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyPastedClass));
 MyPastedClass obj;
 using (var xmlStream = new StringReader(str))
 {
      obj = (MyPastedClass)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely unknown this functionality (I have VS 2012). Very useful.

Comment: you should dispose the StringReader, and that's why it is better to use the using for that manner

Answer (score 0):

Take my class listed bellow. You can serilialize your object to real XML and compare it.

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace VmsSendUtil
{
    /// <summary> Serializes and Deserializes any object to and from string </summary>
    public static class StringSerializer
    {
        ///<summary> Serializes object to string </summary>
        ///<param name="obj"> Object to serialize </param>
        ///<returns> Xml string with serialized object </returns>
        public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));

            var stringSerializer = new StringSerializer<T>();
            return stringSerializer.Serialize(obj);
        }

        /// <summary> Deserializes object from string. </summary>
        /// <param name="xml"> String with serialization XML data </param>
        public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
        {
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml));
            Contract.Ensures(!Equals(Contract.Result<T>(), null));

            var stringSerializer = new StringSerializer<T>();
            return stringSerializer.Deserialize(xml);
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Serializes and Deserializes any object to and from string </summary>
    public class StringSerializer<T>
    {
        [ContractInvariantMethod]
        private void ObjectInvariant()
        {
            Contract.Invariant(_serializer != null);
        }

        private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        ///<summary> Serializes object to string </summary>
        ///<param name="obj"> Object to serialize </param>
        ///<returns> Xml string with serialized object </returns>
        public string Serialize(T obj)
        {
            Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
                _serializer.Serialize(tw, obj);
            }
            string result = sb.ToString();
            Contract.Assume(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result));
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary> Deserializes object from string. </summary>
        /// <param name="xml"> String with serialization XML data </param>
        public T Deserialize(string xml)
        {
            Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml));
            Contract.Ensures(!Equals(Contract.Result<T>(), null));

            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                // Switch off CheckCharacters to deserialize special characters
                var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false };

                var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, xmlReaderSettings);
                var result = (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                Contract.Assume(!Equals(result, null));
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The function of your class also returns me the same exception: 'Error reflecting type 'dllReglasNegocioMP.ReglaRangoResult''

Answer (score 0):

you get an exception that have an hierarchy that you do not define in your code.
if you'll set the right hierarchy it will work.